# groupby_dynamic like method to support the interval index

Tags: rust, rust-polars

something like a

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct IntervalGroupOptions {
    pub index_column: String,
    /// start a window at this interval
    pub every: i32,
    /// window duration
    pub period: i32,
    /// offset window boundaries
    pub offset: i32,
    /// truncate the time column values to the window
    pub truncate: bool,
    // add the boundaries to the dataframe
    pub include_boundaries: bool,
    pub closed_window: ClosedWindow,
}
```

--> get the grouptuple and a broundary as a index

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated in https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/f800a6418d90568798d92603237707dbe68c19bc

currently can use

```rust
        .groupby_dynamic(
            vec![],
            DynamicGroupOptions {
                index_column: "index".to_string(),
                every: Duration::parse("48i"),
                period: Duration::parse("240i"),
                offset: Duration::parse("0i"),
                truncate: false,
                include_boundaries: true,
                closed_window: ClosedWindow::Left,
            },
        )
        .agg([.........]).collect()
```